# Handling matrices in android

Tags: java, android, matrix

I want to create an android application which will have to do some small matrix (dimensions ~6x6) calculations (inversion / sum).

Is there an existing library for doing this?

I have thought about storing the matrix as a multidimensional array, but then accessing single columns is quite unhandy. The best approach that I have found so far was to use the vector class.

Comment: You can use `Eigen` - that's quite handy for android too. I use it as well

Comment: Assuming that you don't need the operations already implemented, you can store it like this: `int[][] matrix = new int[6][6];`, access: `matrix[i][j]`.

Comment: Please check also Jama Matrix. Maybe it will be good for you. https://github.com/fiji/Jama/blob/master/src/main/java/Jama/Matrix.java